# Numeric Transformation of documents

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-processing

I have this dataframe[image]. My aim is to convert each document (eg. D0, D1 ...) with numeric value. And I want the most occuring word gets lower numeric value and less frequent number gets higher value.

For this I have first tokenize my entire document and and have collected all tokens into one single array named corpus[image]. It contains 13k+ words. Now I am not able to find how should I progress. How to encode words according to my requirement and then how can I make this change to my original dataframe using Python.

---

I have tried the code mentioned in comment but Why the same number is occuring for different words. How to reslove this?

[image]

---

Edit 2

I have made the unique dictionary. Now how can I make the changes in my dataframe (remapping the document words with the numeric value according to the dictinary)[image]

For each document every word will be a numeric value according to the dictionary. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for function Counter.
I'm not so sure if you are looking for this output in second part.
[image: Counter]

```
from collections import Counter
text=['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','xx','ddd']
text_to_number = Counter(text)
Counter(text)

[text_to_number[word] for word in text]
```